Does the Power Rule of Integration Apply to Complex Numbers? e.g. $\int x^i\,dx$
$$I=\int x^i\,dx=\int e^{\ln x^i}\,dx=\int e^{i\ln x}\,dx$$
Now I can use Euler's formula and put this in the form $e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$.
$$e^{i\ln x}=\cos(\ln x)+i\sin(\ln x)$$
$$I=\int\cos(\ln x)+i\sin(\ln x)\,dx=\int\cos(\ln x)\,dx+i\int\sin(\ln x)\,dx$$
After computing the integrals and rearranging we are left with:
$$\frac{x}{2}\left ( \cos(\ln x)+i\sin(\ln x) \right )+\frac{-ix}{2}\left ( \cos(\ln x)+i\sin(\ln x) \right )$$
Recalling $e^{i\ln x}=\cos(\ln x)+i\sin(\ln x)$, we can rewrite this as:
$$\frac{x}{2}(x^i)+\frac{-ix}{2}(x^i)$$
$$\frac{1}{2}(x^{i+1})+\frac{-i}{2}(x^{i+1})$$
$$\frac{1-i}{2}(x^{i+1})$$
I notice this is the same result you would get if you assumed the power rule could be extended to $\Bbb C$: $$\int x^i\,dx=\frac{x^{i+1}}{i+1}=\frac{1-i}{2}(x^{i+1})$$
Is this generally true? In this example, it is easy to see the power rule provides the same result as rewriting using Euler's formula, but this would not be the case for other integrals.

The power rule applies, if you are careful about branches and branch cuts.  That is, if $f(z)$ is a branch of $z^\alpha$ that is analytic in a region $U$ of the complex plane, then $f'(z)$ is a branch of $\alpha z^{\alpha - 1}$
that is analytic there, and if $\gamma: [a, b] \to U$ is an arc in this region, $\int_\gamma f'(z)\; dz = f(b) - f(a)$.
But if your path of integration crosses a branch cut, you have to make adjustments.
For example, consider $\int_{\gamma} z^i\; dz$ where $\gamma$ is the straight line from $-1-i$ to $-1+i$, using the "principal branch"
$z^i = \exp(i \operatorname{Log}(z))$, $-\pi \le \text{Im}(\operatorname{Log}(z)) \le \pi$, which has its branch cut on the negative real axis.  If
$F(z) = \frac{1}{1+i} z^{1+i}$, again using the principal branch,
the integral is not $F(-1+i) - F(-1-i)$ but rather
$$F(-1+i) - \lim_{t \to 0+} F(-1+it) + \lim_{t \to 0-} F(-1+it) - F(-1-i)$$

More than anything, I think the OP would want to know if this generalizes to $z^w$, where $z,w\in\mathbb{C}$. I see no reason why it shouldn't,  but the OP is already fairly confident about the case where $w=i$

We are going to prove the Power Rule in general as OP’s suggested
$$
\int x^z d x=\frac{x^{z+1}}{z+1}+C  \text {, where } \quad  z \in \mathbb{C} \backslash \mathbb{R}.
$$
First of all, we need to prove $$\int e^zdz=e^z+C$$
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int e^z d z 
& =\int \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{n!} d z \\
& =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}+c\\&=e^z+C
\end{aligned}
$$
where $C=c+1$ is a constant.
Rewriting the integral as $\int x^z d x=\int e^{z \ln x} d x$ and putting $y=z\ln x$, yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int x^z d x & =\int e^y \cdot \frac{e^{\frac{1}{z}}}{z} d y \\
& =\frac{1}{z} \int e^{\left(1+\frac{1}{z}\right) y} d y \\
& =\frac{1}{z} \frac{e^{\left(1+\frac{1}{z}\right) y}}{1+\frac{1}{z}}+C \\
& =\frac{e^{\left(1+\frac{1}{z}\right) z \ln x}}{z+1}+C\\
& =\frac{\left(e^{\ln x}\right)^{z+1}}{z+1}\\&=\frac{x^{z+1}}{z+1}+C
\end{aligned}
$$
In particular, when $z=i$, we have
$$
\boxed{\int x^i d x=\frac{x^{i+1}}{i+1}+C}
$$
Wish it helps!
